# Do JSF apps really need Shiro's Session management support, when there is already such facility provided by JSF?

Tags: jsf, shiro

I am trying to use Shiro for securing my JSF app. After having a brief look at Shiro I am confused whether JSF applications really need the sessions management facility provided by Shiro. Since JSF already creates sessions when responding to sets of requests received, will using Shiro create (**extra!?**) session instances for the authenticated users ??

I am worried that if I am configuring Shiro for a jsf app then does it create the extra session instances(i am worried since jsf already gives me that & I dont want session instances through shiro)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Shiro by default use the sessions created by the web container. You can configure it to use it's own session management, but I don't think it's necessary in a web app.

Shiro's session management is useful in situations where you don't have a session management facility already (like desktop apps).